# Windows Server 2003 User Logon Audit

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

How to find what all users have logged on my Windows Server 2003. What is the property/setting/service that should be enabled to log all the logons to my server? Is there a way to display an alert mail or message (a script or something) whenever a user logs on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Administrative tools -> Local Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Audit Policy, and on the right pane set the events you'd like to have logged in the event viewer.

As for sending an email or message upon login - you can create a batch file that will do that, and add a shortcut to the programs->startup folder. This will cause the batch to run whenever a user logs in (though not when a user connects to a disconnected session). As for sending an email, there are plenty of free command line emailers on the web, just pick one up. Or, you can NET SEND yourself a message.

Lastly, you'd probably get better answers than these on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com), where more sysadmins would hang out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with Active Directory, you can implement an [audit policy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814595) through GPO.